# A double inequality constrained multi variable optimization problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I’ve been trying to do this for a while now and just cannot figure it out. Essentially, I’ve been asked to optimize the distance between people at a four person table, such that the chairs move in groups of 2 - that is, the two across the table from each other are the same distance x from the corner. This would be easy with a square table, but not so much with a rectangle, as the chairs are not all the same distance from the corner.

Here’s a diagram for further explanation: https://ibb.co/xfRPfx9

Here’s what I need in math terms: I need to maximize the distance between P1 and P2, Dadj1, such that said distance is less than or equal to the distance between P1 and P3, Dlong, & P1 and P4, Dajd2. P1 and P3 are the same distance x away from the corner, and P2 and P4 are the same distance y from the corner.

So far, it seems Lagrange multipliers are the way to go, but I’m struggling with it. Can you even apply them to inequalities? Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $0 < h < b$:

[image]

the proposed optimization problem consists in the study of the function $f : \mathcal{D} \to \mathbb{R}$ of law:

$$
f(x,\,y) := \sqrt{x^2 + (h - y)^2}
$$

in the domain:

$$
\mathcal{D} := \left\{ (x,\,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 
0 \le x \le b, \, 
0 \le y \le h, \,
\sqrt{x^2 + (h - y)^2} \le \sqrt{(b - 2\,x)^2 + h^2}, \\
\sqrt{x^2 + (h - y)^2} \le \sqrt{(b - x)^2 + y^2}\,
\right\}.
$$

---

First of all, it's necessary to simplify the domain, obtaining:

$$
\mathcal{D} = \left\{ (x,\,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 
0 \le x \le \frac{h}{b}\,y + \frac{b^2 - h^2}{2\,b}, \,
0 \le y \le h
\right\}
$$

therefore it's useful to highlight the internal part (green), the borders (blue) and the edges (red):

[image]

This done, we begin the hunt for the critical points of $f$ in $\mathcal{D}$.

In particular, noting that:

$$
\nabla f(x,\,y) = \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + (h - y)^2}}, \, \frac{y - h}{\sqrt{x^2 + (h - y)^2}}\right) \ne (0,\,0) \; \; \; \forall \, (x,\,y) \in \widetilde{\mathcal{D}}
$$

it follows that $f$ has no critical points inside $\mathcal{D}$ (i.e. in $\widetilde{\mathcal{D}}$, green zone).

So, studying $f$ on the borders of $D$ by *parametric method*, noting that:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \gamma_1 : \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,\,0) = \frac{t}{\sqrt{h^2 + t^2}}
\; \; \; \; \; \;
\text{for} \; \; 0 < t < \frac{b^2 - h^2}{2\,b}\,; \\
& \gamma_2 : \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f\left(\frac{h}{b}\,t+\frac{b^2-h^2}{2\,b},\,t\right) = \sqrt{\frac{b^2 + h^2}{(h - 2\,t)^2 + b^2}}\,\frac{2\,t - h}{b}
\; \; \; \; \; \;
\text{for} \; \; 0 < t < h\,; \\
& \gamma_3 : \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(t,\,h) = 1
\; \; \; \; \; \;
\text{for} \; \; 0 < t < \frac{b^2 + h^2}{2\,b}\,; \\
& \gamma_4 : \frac{\partial}{\partial t}f(0,\,t) = -1
\; \; \; \; \; \;
\text{for} \; \; 0 < t < h\,; \\
\end{aligned}
$$

$f$ has only one critical point of coordinates in $\gamma_2$ for $t = \frac{h}{2}$, i.e. at the point $E\left(\frac{b}{2},\,\frac{h}{2}\right)$.

Naturally, applying the *Lagrange multipliers method* four consecutive times, we would have reached the same conclusion, but in cases like this, in my opinion, it's just a waste of time!

Finally, by definition, all four edges of $\mathcal{D}$ are critical for $f$:

$$
A\left(0,\,0\right),
\; \; \;
B\left(\frac{b^2 - h^2}{2\,b},\,0\right),
\; \; \;
C\left(\frac{b^2 + h^2}{2\,b},\,h\right),
\; \; \;
D\left(0,\,h\right).
$$

This done, noting that:

$$
f(A) = h,
\; \; \;
f(B) = \frac{b^2 + h^2}{2\,b},
\; \; \;
f(C) = \frac{b^2 + h^2}{2\,b},
\; \; \;
f(D) = 0,
\; \; \;
f(E) = \frac{\sqrt{b^2 + h^2}}{2}
$$

since $f$ is a continuous function in $\mathcal{D}$, set closed and bounded, by *Weierstrass's theorem*:

$$
\underset{\mathcal{D}}{\min} f(x,\,y) = f(D) = 0 
\; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \; \;
\underset{\mathcal{D}}{\max} f(x,\,y) = f(B) = f(C) = \frac{b^2 + h^2}{2\,b}
$$

as easily verifiable also in *Wolfram Mathematica 12.2* by the following code:

```
{b, h} = {Pi, E};
f[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + (h - y)^2]
domain = ImplicitRegion[{0 <= x <= h/b y + (b^2 - h^2)/(2 b), 0 <= y <= h}, {x, y}];
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, y} ∈ domain, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

I hope it's clear enough, good luck! ^_^